# Creating two lists from a text file

Tags: python, list

I have a text file which consists of inputs:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

I need result or output in the form of:

```
array_1 = [1, 3, 5, 7]
array_2 = [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

I have tried the below code:

```
arr=[]
f = open("file_path","r")
#read line into array

for line in f.read lines():
array_1 = arr.append(line.split()[0])
array_2 = arr.append(line.split()[1])

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you appending and assigning the result? (which is `None`). As a consequence, all numbers land in `arr` and `array_1` and `array_2` are `None`

A few fixes:

- use `append` directly on both lists, forget `arr`
- convert to integer when appending

like this:

```
array_1 = []
array_2 = []
f = open("file_path.txt","r")
#read line into array

for line in f.readlines():
    array_1.append(int(line.split()[0]))
    array_2.append(int(line.split()[1]))
```

now more pythonic:

- don't use `readlines`, read line by line
- split once and unpack with integer conversion on the fly
- use `with` block to open the file, so it's closed when exiting the block

like this:

```
array_1 = []
array_2 = []
with open("file_path.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        item1,item2 = map(int,line.split())
        array_1.append(item1)
        array_2.append(item2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package for processing such file.

You can then get the two arrays from columns the following way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("D:/tmp/file.csv",delimiter=" ", header=None)
array_1 = df[0].values
array_2 = df[1].values
```

And output would be:

```
>>> array_1
array([1, 3, 5, 7], dtype=int64)
>>> array_2
array([2, 4, 6, 8], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please consider to upvote and/or mark the answer as accepted with the tic next to the answer.