# opening txt file and creating lists from the txt file

Tags: python

```
file = open('covid.txt', 'rt')
everything = file.read()
list = file.read()
i = [row.rstrip('\n') for row in everything]
print(i)
    covid = []
    counter = 0
    for number in line.split(" "):
        file.append(number)
    for x in range(4):
        print(x)

file.close()
```

I'm trying to Read the file "covid.txt" into two lists. The first list should contain all the "day" values from the file. The second list should contain all the "new cases" values.

my list in column

```
0 188714 
1 285878
2 1044839
3 812112
4 662511
5 834945
6 869684
7 397661
8 484949
```

I needed to be this way

```
x = [ 0, 1 , 2, 3,...]
y = [188714, 285878, 1044839, 812112, ...]
```

I have tried so many different things I'm new to Python and trying to figure out how to start this. anyone can lead me to the right direction ?

Comment: Please edit your post so that it contains code inside code blocks (i.e. in a text format surrounded by three backticks (`\`\`\``), rather than [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Try the answers to [Creating two lists from a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53856528/16653700).

Comment: `everything` will have the entire file as one long string.  `list` will be empty, because the file is positioned at the end -- you already read everything.  Your `for row in everything` is going to process one character at a time.  You have `line.split`, but `line` is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data file has all of those numbers in one long line, this should work:

```
# Read the words from the file.  This is a list, one word per entry.
words = open('covid.txt','rt').read().split()
# Convert them to integers.
words = [int(i) for i in words]
# Divide into two lists by taking every other number.
x = words[0::2]
y = words[1::2]
print(x)
print(y)
```

### Followup

Given this data:

```
0 188714
1 285878
2 1044839
3 812112
4 662511
5 834945
6 869684
7 397661
8 48494
```

My code produces this result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[188714, 285878, 1044839, 812112, 662511, 834945, 869684, 397661, 48494]
```

which is exactly what you said you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('covid.txt','rt') as f:
    all_lines = [line.split(' ') for line in f]
x, y = zip(*all_lines)
```

`x` and `y` will be tuples though. You can cast by `list(x)`

Comment: You're going to want to strip the lines as well: `all_lines = [line.strip().split(' ') for line in f]` or you get `'188714\n'` for each `y`.